# What is SVN snapshot?

Tags: software-installation, source

In the last lines of website http://gfs.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Mac_OSX_Installation

it says

```
Optional tools
Download the latest SVN snapshot from http://ffmpeg.org/releases/
Unpack and install it.
tar -xvjf ffmpeg-export-snapshot.tar.bz2
cd ffmpeg-export-<insert date here>
./configure --prefix=/opt/gerris
make && make install
```

i enter this website http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ but there are lots of releases . Which one is SVN snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A *snapshot*, in this sense, is the state of the source code at a point in time. It isn't a *release*, where the developers decide that this is a good point to package and distribute a nice, tested version software. A snapshot is whatever is there at this point in time, with the latest features and the latest bugs. Many open source projects provide daily snapshots.

You'll find CVS snapshots, svn (Subversion) snapshots, Git snapshots, Mercurial (hg) snapshots, Bazaar (bzr) snapshots, etc. The qualifier is the version control system used by the developers. Some projects use other adjectives like “nightly snapshot”, and for the result of building that source code, “nightly build”.

Comment: A snapshot is presumably not a random point in time (i.e., in the middle of adding a sequence of patches), so it *should* be safer than just grabbing the work in progress as it stands right now. But your mileage *will* vary. If it breaks, you get to keep the pieces. It might go rummaging in your cookie jar too.

Answer (score 1):

The svn-snapshot is availible for download, use http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2

Comment: Is it the latest version ? it says                          cd ffmpeg-export-<insert date here> what is the date ?

Comment: @user3115779, whatever date appears in the name of the directory that's created by the `tar` command.